# How can I change the width of combobox using the autocomplete jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have several dropdown boxes on my page using the jQuery combobox autocomplete UI. I'd like to reset the width of the comboboxes to some specified dropdown box. How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use this style after link jquery.ui.css .

```
 .ui-autocomplete{
     max-width:200px;
  }
```